# How to calculate the expectation $E[\sigma(1)\sigma(2)\sigma(3)]$, given a 2-wise hash function $\sigma: [d] \rightarrow \{-1,+1\}$

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, random-variables, hash-function

Given a 2-wise hash function $\sigma: [d] \rightarrow \{-1,+1\}$, i.e., $\sigma(a)$ will map any positive integer $a\leq d$
into real number $-1$ or $+1$ with equal probability. Then how to calculate the expectation $E[\sigma(1)\sigma(2)\sigma(3)]$? Here is the definition for **k-wise  independent** http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~sk1233/courses/topics-S13/lec5.pdf

Could someone write the detailed steps? since I am not very sure how to use the definition **2-wise**. Many thanks.